# Некорректный вывод значения максимума/минимума ряда/столбца массива и его расположения

Tags: c++, массивы

Иногда, если при нахождении максимумом/минимумом ряда/столбца двухмерного массива вдруг оказывается ноль или отрицательное значение, то программа почему-то вместо нужного значения ставит везде нули или же значение, указанные в начале по умолчанию в массивах `max_rows`, `min_rows`, `imax_rows`, `imin_rows` и т.д.
**p.s** Значение месторасположения элемента для вывода сдвинуто на 1, если что

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian" );
    srand(time( NULL ));
    const int n = 3, m = 4;
    int a[n][m] = { 0 }, check[n] = { 0 }, check_n[n] = { 0 };
    int max_rows[n] = { -100 }, imax_rows[n] = { 0 }, min_rows[n]= { 100 }, imin_rows[n]={ 0 };
    int max_columns[m] = { -100 }, imax_columns[m] = { 0 }, min_columns[m] = { 100 }, imin_columns[m]= { 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = (rand() % 10) - 5;
            cout << a[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            if (a[i][j] == 0)
            {
                check[i]++; break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            if (check[i] != 0)
            {
                if (a[i][j] < 0) check_n[i]++;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (check[i] != 0)
        {
            cout << "Негативных элементов в ряде " << i + 1 << ": " << check_n[i] << endl;
        }
        else if (check[i] == 0) cout << "Отсутствуют нули в ряде " << i + 1 << endl;
    }cout << endl;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            if (min_rows[i] > a[i][j])
            {
                min_rows[i] = a[i][j];
                imin_rows[i] = j+1;
            }
            else if (max_rows[i] < a[i][j])
            {
                max_rows[i] = a[i][j];
                imax_rows[i] = j+1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (min_columns[j] > a[i][j])
            {
                min_columns[j] = a[i][j];
                imin_columns[j] = i + 1;
            }
            else if (max_columns[j] < a[i][j])
            {
                max_columns[j] = a[i][j];
                imax_columns[j] = i + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Максимум ряда " << i + 1 << ": " << max_rows[i] << ", место максимума: " << imax_rows[i] << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Минимум ряда " << i + 1 << ": " << min_rows[i] << ", место минимума: " << imin_rows[i] << endl;
    }cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        cout << "Максимум колонки " << i + 1 << ": " << max_columns[i] << ", место максимума: " << imax_columns[i] << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        cout << "Минимум колонки " << i + 1 << ": " << min_columns[i] << ", место минимума: " << imin_columns[i] << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0;  j < m; j++)
        {
            if (max_rows[i] == min_columns[j])
            {
                cout << 'A' << i + 1 << '(' << i + 1 << "; " << j + 1 << ')' << "\t";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
-2      -4      2       -2
1       -1      0       -4
2       -2      0       2
Отсутствуют нули в ряде 1
Негативных элементов в ряде 2: 2
Негативных элементов в ряде 3: 1

Максимум ряда 1: 2, место максимума: 3
Максимум ряда 2: 1, место максимума: 1
Максимум ряда 3: 2, место максимума: 1
Минимум ряда 1: -4, место минимума: 2
Минимум ряда 2: -4, место минимума: 4
Минимум ряда 3: -2, место минимума: 2

Максимум колонки 1: 2, место максимума: 3
Максимум колонки 2: 0, место максимума: 0 // тут проблема
Максимум колонки 3: 2, место максимума: 1
Максимум колонки 4: 2, место максимума: 3
Минимум колонки 1: -2, место минимума: 1
Минимум колонки 2: -4, место минимума: 1
Минимум колонки 3: 0, место минимума: 0 // тут проблема
Минимум колонки 4: -4, место минимума: 2
```

Comment: Вы в курсе, что вот такая инициализация, например - `int max_columns[m] = { -100 }` - дает массив, в котором первый элемент равен `-100`, а все остальные - нули?

Answer (score 1):

Если оставить алгоритм как есть, то в коде 2 проблемы:

1. Инициализация массива `{ -100 }` установит первый элемент массива в -100, а остальные в 0. Если нужно установить все элементы в -100 то и указывать нужно все.
2. Условие `if (min_columns[j] > ...) ... else if (max_columns[j] < ...)` в случае срабатывания первого условия, будет пропускать установку максимума и вы получите -100.